# Mathjax doesn't typeset equations after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mathjax

I am using MathJax to typeset equations on my webpage. On loading the webpage for first time everything works fine.On clicking "NEXT" button, equation inside the div changes (ajax call), but it shows up as 'raw TEX' i.e. Mathjax isn't typesetting it the second time. The related code is as follows:

MARKUP AND SCRIPT

```
<div class="div_body" id="ques_dashboard">
  <p>When $a \ne 0$, there are two solutions to \(ax^2 + bx + c = 0\) and they are $$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$</p>
</div>                          
<div class="div_footer">
   <a href="#" class="button ryt_btn" id="answer_submit">SUBMIT</a>
   <a href="#" class="button ryt_btn" id="next_q">NEXT</a>
   <a href="#" class="button ryt_btn" id="skip_q">SKIP</a>
</div>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#next_q').click(function(){
        $("#next_q").hide();
        $('#answer_submit').show();
        $("#skip_q").show();        

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',  
            url: '../ajax/next_question.php',                
            //data:{queslist:queslist, current_qorder:current_qorder},                
            success: function(msg){                        
                $('#ques_dashboard').html(msg);
          MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,'ques_dashboard']);
            }
        });           
        return false;
     }); 
   });
</script>
```

PHP CALLED BY AJAX

```
<?php?>
<p> If \\(a, b, c\\) are in HP, then \\(\\frac {1}{a}, \\frac {1}{b}, \\frac {1}{c}\\) are in AP</p>
```

I have presented here simplified codes, which include lots of php and mysql. I am successfully able to show the "next question" but unable to typeset using Mathjax. I have tried using `MathJax.Hub.Queue` function.

I am new to jquery and ajax. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to track down the problem with the help of [Julien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4867993/julien-gr%C3%A9goire). The code snippet given below was interfering with typeset after ajax call.(This Queue function hides text till the typeset is done.)

`MathJax.Hub.Queue(function () {
document.getElementById("hide_page").style.visibility = "";});`

Commenting this portion solved the problem.

Will update answer in case I find a way to use ajax and "hide until typeset" feature together.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need to escape `'\'` characters, else they are interpreted by `jquery` and underlying `javascript`. So the returned string should be like this:

```
<?php?>
<p> If \\(a, b, c\\) are in HP, then \\(\\frac {1}{a}, \\frac {1}{b}, \\frac {1}{c}\\) are in AP</p>
```

Comment: Nice that u pointed this out. I have edited the question again. As this is simplified example, I forgot this. In my actual code I am using `str_replace('\\','\\\\', $queslist)` before `json_decode` to handle the problem pointed by you($queslist is json_encode sent from first page to second by Ajax). Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: then the problem seems to be somewhere else in your code, because what you show here should work. See working jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9L5xc04e/2/. Maybe somwthing in your MathJax config? Or something in MathJax Queue that blocks this call?

Comment: I just checked my Mathjax config. It was configured to hide text till the typeset is done. Commenting that part solved the problem. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, any idea how to solve the problem without shutting down the "hide until typeset is done" feature?

Comment: are you sure your function doesn't throw any error. What it looks like is as it doesn't go out of the queue. If the function runs correctly it shouldn't block the queue.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that my function isn't throwing any error. But I am not very sure about the queue function (although it isn't throwing any error). I used the code from MathJax Sample files for 'hide till typeset' feature.